# google analytics easytracker causes java connection exception

Tags: android, google-analytics

I started using the Google Analytics platform.
as of now I am able to connect from my **emulator** to G.A servers and upload information.
problem is, when testing from my Samsung Galaxy S the app is not being able to communicate with the G.A servers.

I get the next error:

```
12-17 17:43:21.924: W/GoogleAnalyticsTracker(20577): Problem with socket or streams.
12-17 17:43:21.924: W/GoogleAnalyticsTracker(20577): java.net.ConnectException: www.google-analytics.com/127.0.0.1:80 - Connection refused
12-17 17:43:21.924: W/GoogleAnalyticsTracker(20577):    at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:207)
12-17 17:43:21.924: W/GoogleAnalyticsTracker(20577):    at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:437)
12-17 17:43:21.924: W/GoogleAnalyticsTracker(20577):    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:1002)
12-17 17:43:21.924: W/GoogleAnalyticsTracker(20577):    at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:119)
12-17 17:43:21.924: W/GoogleAnalyticsTracker(20577):    at com.google.android.apps.analytics.PipelinedRequester.maybeOpenConnection(Unknown Source)
12-17 17:43:21.924: W/GoogleAnalyticsTracker(20577):    at com.google.android.apps.analytics.PipelinedRequester.addRequest(Unknown Source)
12-17 17:43:21.924: W/GoogleAnalyticsTracker(20577):    at com.google.android.apps.analytics.NetworkDispatcher$DispatcherThread$AsyncDispatchTask.dispatchSomePendingHits(Unknown Source)
12-17 17:43:21.924: W/GoogleAnalyticsTracker(20577):    at com.google.android.apps.analytics.NetworkDispatcher$DispatcherThread$AsyncDispatchTask.run(Unknown Source)
12-17 17:43:21.924: W/GoogleAnalyticsTracker(20577):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
12-17 17:43:21.924: W/GoogleAnalyticsTracker(20577):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-17 17:43:21.924: W/GoogleAnalyticsTracker(20577):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
12-17 17:43:21.924: W/GoogleAnalyticsTracker(20577):    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
```

I think that there is a problem with my device- could there be a firewall installed on it, and no matter what the problem is- how do I bypass it?

Comment: Are you using analytics sdk for android?

Comment: I am using the [analytics jar](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/mobile/download.html) and the [easytracker jar](http://code.google.com/p/analytics-api-samples/downloads/list)

Comment: I had the same problem until switched to libGoogleAnalyticsV2.jar SDK (available from web property creation page at admin panel)

Comment: The exceptions should have been catched. And manage to not flood by re trying to contact the host like that (cf adb logcat)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think that you use custom ROM or rooted ROM with modified hosts which block (redirect to localhost) all request for analytic tool and banners system.

Related info

- http://pocketnow.com/tweaks-hacks/how-to-surf-faster-on-your-android-using-the-hosts-table
- http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=664532
- http://afreemobile.blogspot.com/2011/09/easy-way-to-block-ads-on-android.html

etc.

Comment: You are so right, That explains why Ads I was trying to add to my app were working on my emulator, but weren't working on the device too

Comment: So if instead of writing 127.0.0.1, we just put a valid ip address who answer HTTP 200 code, the exception don't occur. It's only a way to trick the easy tracker...