# Custom ROMs and Google Analytics

Tags: java, android, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

If a user is using a `Custom ROM` (whatever that is), is it impossible to track them using `Google Analytics`?  The following SO topic makes it sound like this is true.

[google analytics easytracker causes java connection exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8545854/google-analytics-easytracker-causes-java-connection-exception)

Is this true?  If so, do we as developers just chalk those users up as "untrackable"?  That is a little disappointing if true.  Is there a known workaround?

Comment: It seems like it's only true if the user has used an Ad blocker to modify the hosts file

Comment: Even if it *is* true, the number of custom roms compared to overall Android penetration really doesn't seem that important.

Comment: Can you explain @DaveNewton?  I do not follow by what you mean with "Android penetration".  What I am trying to accomplish is to be able to track 100% of my users.

Comment: I understand what you're trying to do. What I'm saying should be pretty clear: most Android users haven't flashed their device, and it's not a big deal.

Comment: It is impossible. The host file is edited, so the device won't communicate with Google. I've installed quite some ROM's on my phone, some of theme have this "feature" included in the ROM itself. It is really annoying, the times I had a ROM with this included I couldn't even check my own Admob statistics. I think it is quite unfriendly for ROM creators to do this, they force developers to sell there apps instead of making them free with ads. Of course there is the Adfree Android app in Google Play for rooted devices, but let the user decide themself.